# SQL returning error: Unknown column "g" in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

Well, there seem to have been many questions on this topic, but mine is weird. 
I run this query:

```
INSERT INTO `blogposts` (id,author,subject,content,date) VALUES (2,$author,$subject,$content,$date)
```

And get this error:

```
Unknown column 'g' in 'field list'
```

I have no column 'g' in my table, so what is happening?

Comment: SQL injection in action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any of the variables you're using are strings, they need to be enclosed in quotes in the query. If one of the variable values is "g", and it's inserted into the query without quotes, MySQL will be looking for the column "g".

```
INSERT INTO `blogposts` (`id`,`author`,`subject`,`content`,`date`) VALUES (2,"$author","$subject","$content","$date")
```

Comment: one more thing: my query is changed to this: INSERT INTO `blogposts` (id,'author','subject','content',date) VALUES (2,$author,$subject,$content,$date) but gives error saying I have something wrong with my syntax. What is it?

Comment: You've put the column names in regular quotes, which is invalid. You need to put the *values* in quotes and the column names in *backticks*. Edited answer with example.

Answer (score 2):

"date" at least is a reserved word, possibly subject is causing problems. Try backticking the column names as well.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't even notice that.